# What is the Equivalent in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

What is the equivalent in XAML? Make Background Red for every Label which are inside a StackPanel.

```
/*In CSS*/
StackPanel Label {
    Background:Red
}

//XAML
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <!-- Condition??? -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a default Style for Labels in a default Style for StackPanels:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```